# u-boot text area overflow when adding command defines

Tags: arm, u-boot

On my `mx53_loco` board i have a problem:
when i add the command line help define (`CONFIG_SYS_LONGHELP`) in the board specific header, building complete successful but when i boot the board i find a corrupted environment (all commmands are unrecognized).

I have this problem even if i increase the size of the `CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS` define.

So it seems to be a problem related to size of the `u-boot` code that overflows somewhere. (`memory map re-definition?`)

I would to be able to resize internal layout of `u-boot` correctly.

Can anyone explain me what happens or suggest a helpful link?

Comment: Try comparing the sizes of the binary files for the different versions of U-Boot with the flash partition allocated to the U-Boot binary.  Also review the flash partition map; is the U-Boot env partition located after the partition for the binary?

Answer (score 0):

u-boot always reads the saved environment variables first. These environment variables are typically in non-volatile memory (NOR or NAND flash, or others). If the CRC of the saved environment variables are correct the saved env variables are used. If you changed your CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS it won't be used!

The values in the CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS will only be used when you reset the env vars to default and save them:

```
$ env default -f
$ saveenv
```

You should also take care of your mapping and sizes. When you add new env variables make sure CONFIG_ENV_SIZE and CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET are correct.
Please read the README file in the top-level directory of the u-boot sources.
And browse the mailing list: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.boot-loaders.u-boot

Edit:
You should also verify that CONFIG_SYS_FLASH_BASE and CONFIG_SYS_MONITOR_LEN are correct. Just make sure you don't overlap the flash area covered by u-boot and the flash area where you write your env variables.